# SQL - Creating multiple columns based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, case

I have never posted before so

1. SQL novice here
2. I hope the formatting comes out correctly

I have been trying to find a way that I can manipulate this data but have yet to find something that I think meets my needs. I need to create additional columns based on the value of another column (in my case, based on the Observation column)

```
PID | Observation_Date | Observation_Time | Obs_Value | Observation

1424285941000610    | 20050603  | 115459    | 110   mm Hg   |BP Systolic  
1424285941000610    | 20050603  | 115459    | 80    mm Hg   |BP Diastolic  
1424285941000610    | 20050603  | 115459    | N             |Smoking Status  
1424285941000610    | 20050912  | 141308    | 110   mm Hg   |BP Systolic  
1424285941000610    | 20050912  | 141308    | 86    mm Hg   |BP Diastolic  
1424285941000610    | 20051027  | 104202    | 195   lb      |Weight  
1424285941000610    | 20051027  | 104202    | 104   mm Hg   |BP Systolic  
1424285941000610    | 20051027  | 104202    | 70    mm Hg   |BP Diastolic  
1424285941000610    | 20060629  | 092852    | 61.5  in      |Height  
1424285941000610    | 20060629  | 092852    | 209   lb      |Weight
```

I have managed to break it out how I would like using multiple case statements but I get something that looks like this:

```
PID Obs_Date    |Obs_Time   |smoking status |bp_dia |bp_sys |Height |Weight  
1424285963050610    |20121203   |161415     |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |180lb  
1424285963050610    |20121203   |161415     |NULL   |NULL   |70in   |NULL    
1424285963050610    |20121203   |161415     |NULL   |138mm Hg   |NULL   |NULL  
1424285963050610    |20121203   |161415     |80mm Hg    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
```

Which will technically work for what I need it for but I know its not correct so I'm hoping I can get it to look something like below where rows are combined based on the observation date

Ideally that it would look something like this:

```
PID |Obs_Date |Obs_Time |smoking status |bp_dia |bp_sys |Height |Weight

1424285963050610    |20121203   |161415     |N  |80 mmHg  |110 mmHg  |null |null
```

I have also tried using nested replace but I end up with the same problem in that it is all in a single column.

I am using `SQL server 2008`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show the query you're using to get that interm result.  You probably just need some MINs or such to group the rows into single row.

Comment: `CASE WHEN obshead.name = 'bp diastolic' THEN obs.value + obshead. unit end as 'bp_dia'
    ,CASE WHEN obshead.name = 'bp systolic' THEN obs.value + obshead. unit end as 'bp_sys'`  ...

Comment: so can you try:  min(CASE WHEN obshead.name = 'bp diastolic' THEN obs.value + obshead. unit end) as 'bp_dia' ,min(CASE WHEN obshead.name = 'bp systolic' THEN obs.value + obshead. unit end) as 'bp_sys'  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.
One is to select the data via correlated subquery.
The other is by table valued subquery.
Another is to just group by the three key fields and do a min and handle the nulls.
I'm going to show the table valued option below.
You can see I've separated the main patient data from each of the observations as it's own data set.  Then linked them on the 3 key fields.

```
SELECT 
   pd.PID, pd.Observation_Date, pd.Observation_Time,
   ss.Obs_Value,
   bpd.Obs_Value,
   bps.Obs_value,
   h.Obs_Value,
   w.Obs_Value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PID, Observation_Date, Observation_Time FROM patient_data) AS pd
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PID, Observation_Date, Observation_Time, Obs_Value FROM patient_data WHERE Observation = 'Smoking Status') AS ss ON (pd.PID = ss.PID AND pd.Observation_Date = ss.Observation_Date AND pd.Observation_Time = ss.Observation_Time)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PID, Observation_Date, Observation_Time, Obs_Value FROM patient_data WHERE Observation = 'BP Diastolic') AS bpd ON (pd.PID = bpd.PID AND pd.Observation_Date = bpd.Observation_Date AND pd.Observation_Time = bpd.Observation_Time)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PID, Observation_Date, Observation_Time, Obs_Value FROM patient_data WHERE Observation = 'BP Systolic') AS bps ON (pd.PID = bps.PID AND pd.Observation_Date = bps.Observation_Date AND pd.Observation_Time = bps.Observation_Time)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PID, Observation_Date, Observation_Time, Obs_Value FROM patient_data WHERE Observation = 'Height') AS h ON (pd.PID = h.PID AND pd.Observation_Date = h.Observation_Date AND pd.Observation_Time = h.Observation_Time)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PID, Observation_Date, Observation_Time, Obs_Value FROM patient_data WHERE Observation = 'Weight') AS w ON (pd.PID = w.PID AND pd.Observation_Date = w.Observation_Date AND pd.Observation_Time = w.Observation_Time)
```

Here is an example of probably the preferred solution which is to just group and take the max.

```
SELECT
   pd.PID, pd.Observation_Date, pd.Observation_Time,
   MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Observation = 'Smoking Status' THEN pd.Obs_Value ELSE '' END) AS [smoking status],
   MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Observation = 'BP Diastolic' THEN pd.Obs_Value ELSE '' END) AS [bp_dia],
   MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Observation = 'BP Systolic' THEN pd.Obs_Value ELSE '' END) AS [bp_sys],
   MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Observation = 'Height' THEN pd.Obs_Value ELSE '' END) AS [Height],
   MAX(CASE WHEN pd.Observation = 'Weight' THEN pd.Obs_Value ELSE '' END) AS [Weight]
FROM patient_data
GROUP BY pd.PID, pd.Observation_Date, pd.Observation_Time
```

All of this is air code, untested.